# Вложенные шаблоны в Go

Tags: golang

Возник вопрос, как использовать вложенные шаблоны в Go. С одним темплейтом нету проблем, а каким образов вызывать несколько?

Comment: вы спрашиваете о вложенных шаблонах?

Comment: да, хочу понять каким образом их правильно использовать

Comment: подскажите где искать информацию и примеры.
[здесь](https://echo.labstack.com/guide/templates) недостаточно информации

Answer (score 1):

Для использования шаблона в Go изнутри другого шаблона используют следующий синтаксис:

```
{{template "template_name"}}
```

где **template_name** - имя шаблона, которое определяется так:

```
{{define "template_name"}}content{{end}}
```

Пример из [документации](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Nested_template_definitions):

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

func main() {
    str := `{{define "T1"}}ONE{{end}}
    {{define "T2"}}TWO{{end}}
    {{define "T3"}}{{template "T1"}} {{template "T2"}}{{end}}
    {{template "T3"}}`
    t := template.Must(template.New("example").Parse(str))
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, nil)
}
```

О го-шаблонах подробнее можете прочесть [здесь](https://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/content/en/07.4.html).